# ReactJS: How to make <div/> float not affect the next <div/>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I currently have:

```
<div style={{float:'left'}}>Left</div>
<div style={{float:'right'}}>Right</div>
<div>Below</div>
```

I was able to get `Left` and `Right` to be on the opposite ends like intended on the same line, but the `Below` is also affected, and floats to the left, right next to `Left`, even though float has not been defined for it.

So I was wondering how to keep `Below` on the next line, without being affected by the previous floats?

Comment: Just a note: the situation is not actually react-specific, its mostly about HTML and would behave the same way in the browser regardless of how it was produced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should clear the last div. Try this:

```
<div style={{clear:'both'}}>Below</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried clearing that last div?

```
clear: both
```